# Hide ERR_Unknown_URL_Scheme page in WebView

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, webview, xamarin.android

I'm using Xamarin Forms using a WebView to display content. To send commands from the webpage to the app, I'm using links with URLs like this:

```
myapp://command=123&someparam=456
```

this is then handled in the PCL project like this:

```
private async void CustomWebView_Navigating(object sender, WebNavigatingEventArgs e) {
    if (e.Url.Contains("myapp://")) {
        e.Cancel = true;
        // Some app logic
    }
    ...
```

This all worked well up until recently when Android phones began displaying an error page saying:

> Webpage not available
>
> ERR_Unknown_URL_Scheme

CustomWebView_Navigating is still being triggered, but **how can I prevent the error page from showing?**

Note: I have tried overriding ShouldOverrideUrlLoading and returning 'true' - but then CustomWebView_Navigating is no longer triggering in the PCL project.

Comment: Use an `intent:` scheme url in your html instead as `a-custom-scheme:` are deemed a security problem (as your app can fake an event to click on it and that is regardless of if you are using the html as a standalone mobile browser or embedded in a Chromium-based WebView) and using a using a `a-custom-scheme:` to launch an app response vs. a browser change was deemed a usability issue by the Chrome team. It does mean that you will have to define the intent filters in the Xamarin.Android side of things and thus capture those events there and re-event/callback them back to your NetStd2 code.